# Cast as double function for Access which is also SQL Server compatible

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a column in my Access database which is of datatype `Text` while the values stored in there are usually numbers. I say usually because the users need to be able to enter things like `<MDL` or `<0.0095` but also need to be able to enter, more usually, things like `1.25`, i.e. actual numbers. So the column has to be accommodating to text. Also, there was never (until today) really a reason to do any math with that column. The data is just being passed through to the user to view so `Text` was a fine choice.

Now my problem is I need to make a crosstab query and take the average of this column for the value field. I can make the cast using either the `Val` or `Cdbl` function  but when the client eventually wants to switch this thing over to SQL server I will need to go and change that function to a `CAST(column as float)` as far as I can tell.

Is there a function common to Access and SQL server I can use so that I don't need to go through and make a change like this to my query when we switch DB engines?

I'm not sure what version of SQL server they're running yet but I'd assume 2005 until told otherwise.

Comment: I would think you're going to be making a lot of changes switching from Access to SQL Server, and one syntax change for a cast isn't going to make or break the migration; comment and move on.  That said, I don't believe there is any shared syntax to do this.  If DBMS independence is truly paramount, then you'd probably want to put this type of logic in your application, not a SQL query.

Comment: If the paramount requirement is the same SQL statement must run correctly in either db, create a VBA function to wrap `CDbl()` for Access, and a T-SQL function with the same name in SQL Server.  Use the function name in your query.

Comment: @TimLehner I guess you're right but if I could avoid this one thing that would have been nice.